# How to create tree charts using drag and drop components from a palette in angular?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I am working with angular 15. I need to create an area in which we can drag and drop components from a palette to form a n-ary tree.

I have looked into some libraries but i dont know if it fits my case, like d3js chartjs, or google charts which will be more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this? This can be done in vanilla JavaScript -- no frameworks needed.

```js
document.querySelector('ul.palette').addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.dataset.id);
});

document.querySelector('ul.tree').addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.over')]
  .forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('over'));
  e.target.classList.add('over');
});

document.querySelector('ul.tree').addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  let sourceElm = document.querySelector(`li[data-id="${id}"]`);
  let type = sourceElm.dataset.type;
  let clone = sourceElm.cloneNode(true);
  if (type == 'folder') {
    let ul = document.createElement('UL');
    clone.append(ul);
  }
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
    e.target.closest('ul').insertBefore(clone, e.target)
  } else {
    e.target.closest('ul').append(clone);
  }
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.over')]
  .forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('over'));
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15vw auto;
}

ul.palette {
  grid-column: 1;
}

ul.tree {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: WhiteSmoke;
  align-self: start;
  min-height: 1em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
  padding: 0 0 .5em 0;
  border-bottom: solid tranparent medium;
}

ul.over {
  border-bottom: solid black medium;
}

li.over {
  border-top: solid black medium;
}

li {
  padding-top: .2em;
  border-top: solid transparent medium;
}
```

```html
<ul class="palette">
  <li draggable="true" data-id="1" data-type="item">Item 1</li>
  <li draggable="true" data-id="2" data-type="item">Item 2</li>
  <li draggable="true" data-id="3" data-type="folder">Folder</li>
</ul>
<ul class="tree">
</ul>
```